# System error after debugging multithreaded applications

Tags: windows, multithreading, delphi

After debugging a multithreaded application, I have error of the system library 'ntdll.dll'.
Error code is 0x4000001f (STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT).
Error occurs on a case by case, and only when debugging via the Delphi IDE. 
I use Delphi 2010 on Win7 x64.
In what may be problem? Thanks.

Comment: Can you reproduce this with ANY multi-threaded app, or just one specific app? If the latter, try to reproduce in an App that is as small as possible.

Comment: This can't be answered in this form. I vote to close, not a real question.

Comment: @david-heffernan Ok. Real question. What are possible causes STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT?

Comment: That's explained in ntstatus.h. Specifically it states: "Exception status code used by Win32 x86 emulation subsystem." Somewhat less than useful!

Comment: What's in your app? What does it link to? Does it use COM? CLR? Can you reproduce in any meaningful way? Without details like this your problem is going to be tough for others to solve.

Comment: Nothing specific, such as COM, CLR. Just console app + BeginThread/EndThread + CriticalSection. All threads completed before app closing and no dead lock.

Comment: I think, Delphi debugger and x86 emulator does not working correctly, but I not so sure.

Answer (score 0):

I have witnessed this occur on only one computer, though we never did discover EXACTLY what caused it. The error occured with ANY multithreaded application attached to the debugger (no matter what the threads were doing). In the end we reformatted and reinstalled the machine, the problem disappeared.
I'm not suggesting you SHOULD format and reinstall, but... if all else fails!